# DHTMLXGantt with ReactJS setting work_time

Tags: reactjs, dhtmlx

I am trying to use DHTMLXGantt on my reactJs project, and I have gone through their [tutorial](https://dhtmlx.com/blog/create-react-gantt-chart-component-dhtmlxgantt/) when setting it up. Now I want to modify it to only consider the working hours by adding `gantt.config.work_time = true` which seems pretty straightforward. 
However, when I add it, it still doesn't display only the work time (08hr - 17hr), rather shows hours from 00hr - 23hr on the gantt as below:

[image]

Would really appreciate if anyone has tried a similar thing and got it working. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Enabling worktime won't automatically change the time scale,
you'll need to hide columns using [gantt.ignore_time](https://docs.dhtmlx.com/gantt/desktop__custom_scale.html) function

```
gantt.ignore_time = function(date){
   if(!gantt.isWorkTime(date))
      return true;
};
```